# How to get out only change record from daily level data?

Tags: oracle

I have a huge amount stock data. We are tracking every day stock level amount. My purpose is to get query which take records only when the amount is change:

Sample:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query with subquery:

```
Select date_id, product,warehouse,amount
From 
(
  Select 
      date_id, product, warehouse, amount, 
      lag(amount) over (partition by product, warehouse order by date_id) amount_prev
  From TABLENAME
) x
Where amount <> amount_prev
```

Comment: I hope I got the windowing function syntax 100% correct :)

Comment: That one is correct, but I needed a FROM inside the parenthesis .... done

Comment: @LarsGOlsen This answer does provide the correct output. Having said that, require a small correction, instead of *, use the column names as `date_id, product, warehouse, amount, ` See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7ed7418db19e41312b1be453de1553dc)

Comment: Thanks for testing my ‘braindump’ Code... on most databases, I would expect * to work fine, but I have corrected anyway.. does not hurt I guess :)